# Follow GameObject in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, path-finding

Iam newbie in Unity3D, so please help me. :)

I have two objects:
**Player** and 
**Enemy**
and I need follow Player by Enemy.
I tried something like this:

```
var player : GameObject;

function Start ()
{
    var agent: NavMeshAgent = GetComponent.<NavMeshAgent>();
    agent.SetDestination(player.transform.position);
}
function Update () {

}
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: Did you bake your Navmesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Update` method run the code every frame, so if you have movement operations put your code in the update method. I have never heard about a `NavMeshAgent`.

**#1:** The easiest way is to add an [rigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) object to your `GameObject` and use the method `MovePosition()`.

**#2:** The second way is to set the `gameObject` as a child from the `gameObject` which it should follow. Than unity perform the translations.

**#3:** You also can calculate the position by yourself, but first of all you should learn something more about unity.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there is obstacles(Rectangles). I want to avoid them.

Comment: Can you pls mark the answer as accepted if it fixed your problem? What do you mean with obstacles?

Comment: Sure.. I mean walls etc. :)

Comment: Thats another point. You should read something about collisions etc. The best way to learn are some youtube tutorials I think.